# bootstrap 4 modal function not working on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a modal that when the button for it is clicked an action occurs for this example write to the console. The modal is opening but event is not happning.

HTML File

```
<button type='button' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>
Open modal
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
```

JS File

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){
  $(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
      console.log('new button clicked');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Why do you have two `</button>`?

Comment: I just ran your code as a snipplet and it worked so...... what is different?

Answer (score -1):

```
<button type='button' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
```

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
```

try above this will open your modal ... you just had two closing tags of button i.e `</button>`

Answer (score -2):

**Your code works perfectly by the way**

```js
$('button[data-target="#myModal"]').on( "click", function() {
  console.log('clicked')
});

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  console.log('modal opened')
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type='button' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "it works" is never an answer. At best it's a comment